# How to arrange a dataframe on a chosen column, while keeping two specific rows at the top?

Tags: r, shiny, tidyverse

I have a table with many samples. I would like to have Positive & Negative controls at the top of the table, but need help figuring out the most straighforward way to do this.

Here is a minimal example dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(structure(list(Well = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2"), 
                               Sample = c("Asample 2", "Positive control", "Asample 1", "Negative control"))))
```

The task:

- Positive & negative controls at the top of the table.
- The rest of the table arranged by `well` and **NOT** the `sample` name.
- Keep in mind that positive & negative controls are always named like this, but could have any random well id in real life situation, whereas sample names and well ids can vary.

The desired output:

```
  well  sample          
  <chr> <chr>           
1 A2    Positive control
2 B2    Negative control
3 A1    Asample 2       
4 B1    Asample 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution:

```
df %>% arrange(match(Sample,c("Positive control", "Negative control")),Well)

  Well           Sample
1   A2 Positive control
2   B2 Negative control
3   A1        Asample 1
4   B1        Asample 2
```

Comment: This won't work if "Negative control" comes before "Positive control" in the data

Comment: It still works, but negative control appears on top instead. This should not be an issue as long as controls are at the top of the table. But since you mentioned this, is there a way to specify the order if this is desired?

Comment: You could use `match` to specify the order : `df %>% arrange(match(Sample,c("Positive control", "Negative control")),Well)`

Comment: Cool, didn't know about `match`

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to make `sample` a `factor()` using `well` levels, and then to relevel `sample` appropriately.

```r
df %>% 
    arrange(Well) %>% 
    mutate(
        Sample = fct_relevel(
            fct_inorder(factor(Sample)), 
            c('Positive control', 'Negative control')
        )
    ) %>% 
    arrange(Sample)
```

```
  Well           Sample
1   A2 Positive control
2   B2 Negative control
3   A1        Asample 2
4   B1        Asample 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work as the dataframe is arranged by the sample name at the end and not the well id (see the improved minimal df example). In reality, samples can be named as anything meaning Sample 2 could need to appear before Sample 1 based on well id.

Comment: You're right! Forgot to add `fct_inorder` - now it should work

Comment: This works, thank you! Since this is for the shiny app, I accepted the shorter solution suggested by Waldi, but this does exactly the same.